# Making room to take a photo - transfer to the cloud

Tags: storage

How do I manage my settings so that I can take a picture?  My storage says I have 11.76GB used and Available Zero KB.  I actually have 32.49 GB available in Icloud....How do I free up space and how do I take what I have and transfer to the cloud?  Thanks for your help - J

Comment: Do you have iCloud turned on in the iPhone (assuming you have an iPhone because you didn't say what you are using in your question)?  See [this iMore article](http://www.imore.com/how-free-space-your-iphone-or-ipad-icloud-photo-library) for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on an iPhone and I found that all the pictures I deleted went to a trash bin (Recently Deleted). Until that is emptied, the storage will not free up.